# How do you pull entries with a specific category value?

Tags: templating

Help, I forgot how to do something basic.

How do I pull all the entries in `posts` for a specific category value (field name = `countryName`) within the category group called `country`?

And I am ***NOT*** using the template for posts or the category.

I can pull all the entries using

`{% for doc in craft.entries.section('posts') %}`
--*OR*--

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('posts') %}`

But, I forgot how to now add a second condition to pull up only those entries with the `countryName` (say) "United Kingdom"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the best way to do it?

```
`{% set results = craft.entries.section(posts).search('countryName:"United Kingdom"') %}
```

It appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('posts').countryName('United Kingdom') %}` should do the trick

EDIT: 
`{% set results = craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo('United Kingdom').find() %}`

Comment: It does not.  It does not cause an error.  But nothing is written.  And everything appears when I remove the appended `.countryName('United Kingdom').  And, I double checked the field name and I tried multiple country names.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I didn't realize the country name was also a category. Would `{% set results = craft.entries.section('posts').relatedTo('United Kingdom').find() %}`
 work?